# present simple or future in this case

Tags: present-tense, future-tense

I've just sent a book to someone. What should I say, when I write, to let him know the book has been sent?

> let me know when the book **is** with you

or

> let me know when the book **will be** with you

What tense should I use **present or future**? I think both are correct

Comment: Neither. You should say "Let me know when the book arrives."

Comment: **or** Let me know when you *get* the book!

Answer (score 3):

You should use present simple in this case. Let me know when the book is with you. Because only when he gets the book, he will let you know the fact that the book is with him.

from the other parth's perspective, he may ask you "Let me know when the book will be with me", in this case, he wants to know how long he has to wait for receiving this book.